# Index not showing in Kibana 6.2

Tags: python, django, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-6, kibana-6

So I'm using Elasticsearch and Kibana to show specific user events that my Django App sends with elastic-py. I was using the 5.5 version before and it worked great, but for different reasons, I had to change the server itself and decided to use this opportunity to upgrade to ELK 6.x.

So I set up a new fresh install of Elasticsearch and Kibana 6.2.2 in another server with the X-Pack also and did a few tweaks to my old code:

Before

```
. . . 
'mappings': {
   'example_local': {
      'properties': {
         'action': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'string'},
         'date': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'format': 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'type': 'date'},
         'user_type': {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'string'},
. . .
```

After

```
. . . 
  'mappings': {
    'example_local': {
       'properties': {
          'action': {'type': 'text'},
          'date': {'format': 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'type': 'date'},
          'user_type': {'type': 'text'},
. . .
```

After that, I added the user and password to my connection, one thing that in my old ELK couldn't do.

```
host_port = '{}:{}'.format(settings.ELASTICSEARCH['host'], settings.ELASTICSEARCH['port'])
Elasticsearch(host_port, http_auth=(settings.ELASTICSEARCH['username'],settings.ELASTICSEARCH['password']))
```

And at last, I created my index and went running to Kibana to see how my last 4 hours of struggle finally paid off.

But in the **Management** -> **Kibana** -> **Index Patterns** there was only 1 index, ***haystack-test***  (I don't know why it was there) .

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know what happened but I was quite sad, so I started from scratch with a 6.2 Elasticsearch tutorial and checking the index patterns window after each command line until I saw that the Index appeared after I did an insert/update in the index.

So from my Django I sent an event and after that the index showed in the Kibana window.

So in case anyone has a similar problem here is my solution.